# How can I roll up my sleeves in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom

Is there a Latin idiom for preparing for work?
In English one can roll up one's sleeves, and the corresponding expression has the same meaning in Finnish.
I doubt a direct translation of this idiom works in Latin, especially classical Latin, since sleeves were not as common in antiquity as they are today.

If you can suggest an idiom, please indicate if it is related to a specific kind of work or has other context restrictions.
I prefer classical Latin, but also later expressions are welcome.
If your suggestion is not attested in literature, please explain why it is good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Cingo* or *accingo* "gird" might be what you're looking for. In the passive (with a reflexive meaning), these verbs are often used in the sense of "prepare for" (some effort).

Lewis and Short on [*cingo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=cingo):

> As a girding up of the Roman dress was necessary in pursuits requiring physical action, hence, cingor (cf accingor), *to make one's self ready for any thing, to prepare*: “cingitur, certe expedit se,” Plaut. Am. 1, 1, 152; “cingitur ipse furens certatim in proelia Turnus,” Verg. A. 11, 486.

And on *[accingo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daccingo)*:

> accingere se or accingi, *to enter upon or undertake a thing, girded,* i. e. *well prepared, to prepare one's self, make one's self ready* (taken from the girding of the flowing robes when in active occupation); constr. *absol.*, with *ad, in,* dat., or *inf*.: “tibi omne est exedendum, accingere,” *make yourself ready, Ter. Ph. 2, 2, 4*; so id. Eun. 5, 9, 30; Lucr. 2, 1043: “illi se praedae accingunt,” Verg. A. 1, 210: “accingi ad consulatum,” Liv. 4, 2.

Comment: Oh, I like your suggestions.

Comment: Is that the origin of "to gird one's loins"?

Comment: @JAB: "gird your loins" (=accingere lumbos) is a Biblical expression: for example, Jer 1:17, 2 Kings 4:29, Prov 31:17, and (NT) Eph 16:14

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, thank you! It also has a similar tone with the English expression, since both have to do with adapting one's clothing to work.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is not entirely idiomatic, a word that I find evocative and powerful is:

## obnitor, obniti(er), obnixus ([L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dobnitor))

It has military connotations of "standing firm":

> *stant **obnixa** omnia contra* (Verg, A. 10, 359)
>
> ***obnixos** vos stabili gradu impetum hostium excipere* (Liv. 6, 12)

as well as more general meanings of "striving":

> *triumphum Pauli impedire **obnitebantur*** (Vell. 1, 9, 6.)
>
> ***obnixe** omnia facere* (Ter. And. 1, 1, 134)

This might not exactly fit the bill of what you're describing: but I recall asking a Latin professor of mine what this word meant many years ago and he (true to the natural method) remained silent and rolled up his sleeves until I understood.